# Number format exception in string to integer parsing

Tags: java, android, parsing, type-conversion

I know this question ask many time here. Actually i also refer some of them but not able to get solution so decided to post here

I am simply trying to parse string value to integer at that time it gives Null pointer exception. 
When i am trying to print value of string i get 5 which is correct but when i print their value after parse it is 0. Following the code which i have tried

```
String xmldata = "";
int sql_proID;
xmldata = os.toString();
sql_proID = Integer.parseInt(xmldata);
```

I also tried by declaring sql_proID as long but it gives same error.
following is exception message

```
01-04 17:06:14.166: W/System.err(398): java.lang.NumberFormatException: unable to parse  '
01-04 17:06:14.166: W/System.err(398): 5' as integer
01-04 17:06:14.166: W/System.err(398):  atjava.lang.Integer.parse(Integer.java:383)
01-04 17:06:14.176: W/System.err(398):  at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:372)
01-04 17:06:14.176: W/System.err(398):  at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:332)
01-04 17:06:14.176: W/System.err(398):  at com.example.anti_dui_app.Synchronization.onCreate(Synchronization.java:57)
01-04 17:06:14.176: W/System.err(398):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
01-04 17:06:14.176: W/System.err(398):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
01-04 17:06:14.176: W/System.err(398):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
01-04 17:06:14.176: W/System.err(398):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
01-04 17:06:14.176: W/System.err(398):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
01-04 17:06:14.176: W/System.err(398):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-04 17:06:14.185: W/System.err(398):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
01-04 17:06:14.185: W/System.err(398):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
01-04 17:06:14.185: W/System.err(398):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-04 17:06:14.185: W/System.err(398):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
01-04 17:06:14.185: W/System.err(398):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
01-04 17:06:14.185: W/System.err(398):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
01-04 17:06:14.185: W/System.err(398):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

where i goes wrong please tell me...thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like there may be a newline char in there.

Have you tried trimming the string to remove whitespace?

e.g:

sql_proID=Integer.parseInt(xmldata.trim());

Answer (score 5):

It looks like you are getting five with single quotes, which is the reason for NullPointerException.

Please also check that there is a new line existing as showing in logcat.

Answer (score 4):

It is a `NumberFormatException` not a `NullPointerException`. It is caused by an ill-formated number string that seems to be `"\n5"` instead of just `"5"`.

Comment: @karthi it was an independent answer given at the same time (just 24 seconds later if you look at the time stamp)

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not clear and up to the mark as:

```
String **xmldata**="";
int sql_proID;
xmldata = os.toString();
sql_proID=Integer.parseInt(xmldata);
```

Here you are parsing **xmldata** which is having value '5'.
It is not understandable for parser.
So try to get value as only 5.